# Cross product in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, optimization

I'm trying to make a cross product between two vectors R^n , is there any way to do this in the most optimized way?

I have looked on the accelerate library but still can not find anything

Comment: I believe you are looking for GLKit: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKit_Collection/ It has native support for vector multiplication. There are also multiple 3rd party libraries: for example, https://github.com/nicklockwood/VectorMath

Answer (score 1):

> A cross product can exist in Rn if and only if n=0, 1, 3 or 7

Source: http://www.math.csusb.edu/faculty/pmclough/CP.pdf

So no, you certainly won't find any library that does that. If you meant the element-wise, you can use Accelerate. Here is a short test:

```
import Accelerate

let n = 10_000_000

let a = (0..<n).map{ _ in Double(arc4random()) / Double(UInt32.max) }
let b = (0..<n).map{ _ in Double(arc4random()) / Double(UInt32.max) }

print("A: [\(a.prefix(10).map{ "\($0)" }.joinWithSeparator(", ")), ...]")
print("B: [\(b.prefix(10).map{ "\($0)" }.joinWithSeparator(", ")), ...]")

var result = [Double](count: n, repeatedValue: 0)

let start = mach_absolute_time()
vDSP_vmulD(a, 1, b, 1, &result, 1, UInt(n))
let stop = mach_absolute_time()

let time = Double(stop - start) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)

print("Time: \(time) for \(n) elements")
print("Result: [\(result.prefix(10).map{ "\($0)" }.joinWithSeparator(", ")), ...]")
```

Output:

```
A: [0.269752697849123, 0.851672558312228, 0.0668649589798564, 0.0955562389212559, 0.255900985620893, 0.93693982901446, 0.085282990495973, 0.732230591525377, 0.588338787804437, 0.952581417968632, ...]
B: [0.750105029379508, 0.0454008649209051, 0.863010750120275, 0.308104009904923, 0.700024090637459, 0.327355608653127, 0.679469040520366, 0.666848364208557, 0.0567599588671606, 0.623293806245386, ...]
Time: 0.024393279 for 10000000 elements
Result: [0.202342855345318, 0.0386666707767751, 0.0577051784059674, 0.0294412603830718, 0.179136854752495, 0.306712507998386, 0.0579471517250063, 0.488286772182162, 0.0333940853957349, 0.593738097764296, ...]
```

0.024 seconds for 10 million elements is pretty fast

Answer (score 1):

### Parallel execution

If you are looking for the Elementwise product operation

> a = (1.0, 2.0)
>
> b = (3.0, 4.0)
>
> a * b = (a1*b1, a2*b2) = (3.0, 8.0)

and you want the fasted possible performance available on iOS you should use the `simd` framework (Single Instruction Multiple Data).

```
import simd

let v0 = float2(1.0, 2.0)
let v1 = float2(3.0, 4.0)

let res = v0 * v1
print(res) // float2(3.0, 8.0)
```

### Why is simd so fast?

Without simd, calculating `a*b` would required the execution of 2 steps

1. calculate `a1 * b1` and put the result into `res1`
2. calculate `a2 * b2` and put the result into `res2`

On the other hand, using `simd` both operations are done in parallel. This is possible because the 2 steps have the **same operation** with **different data**. This is exactly what `simd` does allow you do to.

### More

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD)

> Single instruction, multiple data (SIMD), is a class of parallel computers in Flynn's taxonomy. It describes computers with multiple processing elements that perform the same operation on multiple data points simultaneously.
>
> Thus, such machines exploit data level parallelism, but not concurrency: there are simultaneous (parallel) computations, but only a single process (instruction) at a given moment.
>
> SIMD is particularly applicable to common tasks like adjusting the contrast in a digital image or adjusting the volume of digital audio.
>
> Most modern CPU designs include SIMD instructions in order to improve the performance of multimedia use.